# Assigning unique number to each instance of objects

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, testing, squish

So, I have a task to uniquely name all swing components in quite a big project, naming convention beeing name_of_containing_classnumber_of_its_instance/name_of_variable_holding_component. So I made a program to automatically search all the code base and after each initailization of swing component it names it approprietly. I get instance numbers from this static method:

```
public static int getInstanceNumber(Object instance) {
    if (instancesMap.get(instance.getClass()) != null) {
        List<Object> instances = instancesMap.get(instance.getClass());
        if (!instances.contains(instance)) {
            instances.add(instance);
            return instancesMap.get(instance.getClass()).size();
        } else {
            return instances.indexOf(instance) + 1;
        }
    } else {
        ArrayList<Object> instances = new ArrayList<Object>();
        instances.add(instance);
        instancesMap.put(instance.getClass(), instances);
        return instancesMap.get(instance.getClass()).size();
    }
}
```

And i use it like some_component.setName(className+getInstanceNumber(this)/variable_name);

It gets the job done, my my problem is I need this naming to be consistent across execution. What do I need to look at to make sure that threading doesn't get in the way, or how could I approach it differently to not have the problem of different naming in different execucions (assuming we move through the same path in the application).

I need those names for squish automated tests, so each time we execute the same test, we need the same names for the exact same swing components/

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to completely rework this. In this setup threading will throw you off, but if anyone ever changes the code it will renumber everything that calls this method after it does.

I would suggest either hardcoding the name, using the name of the class, or look to at what the objective is behind this requirement and see if there are alternatives.